# How to keep first element from jCarousel static or fixed to it's position?

Tags: php, jquery, jcarousel

I have added jCarousel to the HTML Form which has multiple columns.

For example: I have list of cars arranged first column and then it will have feature list of these cars in 8 columns which user can set using input fields.

If I set the list of cars outside of jCarousel it will not lined-up with input fields since some feature text needs multiple lines and if I add it inside jCarousel DIV User will not be able to see the name of car on scrolling to next fetatures.

Can anybody please help me to set first column static/fixed? so that if user clicks on button to scroll to next feature list of cars will be visible for all the feature.

All suggestions are welcome

Comment: give some part of your code??

Comment: @user1145009 Thanks for offering help.... please wait I am adding the code to jsfiddle

Comment: @user1145009 I want to make Feature column static/fixed so that on scrolling it should stay there at all time ... link is here http://jsfiddle.net/RX4BT/11/ ...

Comment: Take a look ..have a made a quick demo ..will update it later

Answer (score 0):

```
.stays-at-top {
    background-color: #f99;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/RX4BT/12/)**

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just checked the demo and observed that div stays there on first click on scroll arrow buttons but on further clicks on back and forth div hides the div forever

Comment: I am referring to [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/RX4BT/12/)... I want to keep first column i.e. colored Feature list as it is even if user clicks on navigation arrow buttons. 
**Reason-** If I keep these feature list outside the `jCarousel DIV` then feature rows and input fields present in `jCarousel DIV`are not getting lined up because some of the features has more number of characters and they occupy space on multiple lines

Comment: so you dont want that div ..Instead it could be first `li` ..and it should be fixed at the top even after scroll ?? am i right??

Comment: Yes... that's perfect

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help... It's working perfectly in above fiddle link but not working in my page... I am trying to figure out..may be I have vertical scroll bar on page so I think that might be creating some issue